# "cannot execute binary file: Exec format error" hdfs command

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop, hdfs

When I try to run the command

```
hdfs nodename -format
```

I get this error message:

> /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs: line 304: /usr/local/Java/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
>
> /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs: line 304: /usr/local/Java/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java: Success

Now, I opened hdfs file and this is the line 304:

```
exec "$JAVA" -Dproc_$COMMAND $JAVA_HEAP_MAX $HADOOP_OPTS $CLASS "$@"
```

I don't know what java is trying to execute, but something is wrong in this execution. Please help me to figure out why. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm assuming your command is a typo? The command would be `hdfs namenode -format`

Comment: Yes, I typed wrong, it's namenode.

Answer (score 2):

Check the version of Java that you installed on your system. Use the following command to see your machine architecture:

```
uname -a
```

It should be the same as the version of Java when you execute. :

```
java -version
```

Let's say both of them are compiled for 64-Bit architecture.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Unfortunately, system is 32-bit, and java is correctly installed for 32-bit.

Comment: what is your kernel version and release? use (uname -v) and (uname -r)

Comment: uname -v   ->  #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:30:01 UTC 2014

Comment: uname -r  -> 3.13.0-37-generic

Comment: type this on your system. and post the result please.                                echo $JAVE_HOME

Comment: Here it is       /usr/local/Java/jdk1.7.0_79